# Ignore map object Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've got a recursive method for getting content of a directory, but I want to ignore certain object (e.g. if it's a .DS_store or something) but how can I get it to ignore it and carry on without returning a value.

Something like this but obviously *continue* doesnt work...

```
 ...
    info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).map(function(child) {

        if (child.indexOf('.') == 0) 
            continue;

        return dirTree(filename + '/' + child);
    });
 ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) itself performs 1:1 mapping, output array will contain the same number of elements as input array.

But you could chain [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods:

```
info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).filter(isValidFile).map(doStuff);

// Used to filter out unwanted entries (files)
function isValidFile (child) {
  return (child !== '.DS_store' && child.indexOf('.') !== 0);
}

// Used to perform your actual logic
function doStuff (child) {
  return dirTree(filename + '/' + child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to first get only the right array elements and then `map`.

Something like:

```
...
info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).filter(function (child) {
    return child.indexOf('.') !== 0;
}).map(function (child) {
    return dirTree(filename + '/' + child);
});
...
```